# Can a hacker use someone else's IP address when running a scam?

Tags: malware, ip-spoofing, email-spoofing

I have a friend who works on a ship currently in Accra, Ghana.  We do video chats but his system is extremely slow and sluggish. There have been times where our only form of communication is IM.

A few times I have felt like I was not communicating with my friend. I started to make a note of emails that appeared to come from him but were not written in his 'voice'.

I recently checked the IP addresses of these unusual emails and found that they were connected to previous scams. However the IP addresses of his earlier emails did not have any red flags. So I am wondering if his system has been corrupted or hacked.

If so, what can be done to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

If the suspicious emails are from a consistently different IP than the trusted emails, then it seems unlikely that his computer is compromised. Instead, it sounds like someone has found a way to spoof his email address, using their own computer to send it.

Without knowing more information, I can't really speculate as to why someone is doing this. However, there are steps that can be taken to verify that emails are actually coming from your friend, rather than a scammer.

One approach you could use is to [sign the message using PGP](http://www.pgp.net/pgpnet/pgp-faq/pgp-faq-message-signatures.html). In order for that to work, you would both have to set up a mail client (or use a plugin) that knows how to deal with PGP signatures, and then your friend would have to generate keys and send you the public key somehow. At that point, you'd be able to verify that future emails are coming from the "correct" source - or at least, from the source that originally gave you a public key. To really be safe, you'd also want to confirm the key's fingerprint using a trusted channel (like voice chat), in order to verify that the public key *is* actually from your friend, rather than from some malicious third party.

There are other approaches that could be used on your end to check whether a message is legitimate, although those are likely to involve a bit more specific knowledge about the email servers involved. In comparison, PGP will work in any context, although it requires that both parties have at least a bit of extra cybersecurity knowledge.